# Google Maps Circles like iPhone/Android default Maps apps

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, drawing

I know how to create Markers, Circles, infoWindows etc etc in Google Maps V3.I need to know how would I create a circles with Lat/Lng, radius and ofcourse with some color that **Starts from center and than disappear with certain radius and do the same again. Just like in Mobile Appplications**.

When we launch Google Maps on any iPhone/Android its show the current location with circle appearing and disappearing.I need that type of circle in my Web Application.

In my Application currently i am checking the Zoom level and than showing/hiding the circles on map with below code.But I need to know that my Circles Appear from start and than disappear up to certain radius and do the same again just like the default Mobile Applications Maps.
Any Hint Please ?

```
data = $.parseJSON(data);
google.maps.visualRefresh = true;

var draw_circle = [];
var count = data.length;
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
    var zoomLevel = map.getZoom();
    if(zoomLevel >= 15){
       $.each(data, function(i,j){ 
        var marker = new google.maps.LatLng($(j).attr('lat'),$(j).attr('lng'));
        var strokeColor = ($(j).attr('colName') == 0) ? '#FF0000' : '#00ff7f';
                    if(draw_circle[i] == null){
                        draw_circle[i] = new google.maps.Circle({
                            center: marker,
                            radius: parseInt($(j).attr('gft')),
                            strokeColor: strokeColor,
                            strokeOpacity: 0.6,
                            strokeWeight: 2,
                            fillColor: strokeColor,
                            fillOpacity: 0.35,
                            map: map
                        });
                    }
                });
            }else if(zoomLevel >= 0 && zoomLevel < 15){
                for(var a = 0; a < count; a++){
                    if(draw_circle[a] != null){
                        draw_circle[a].setMap(null);
                        draw_circle[a] = null;
                    }
                }     
            }
        });
```